# Python HTTPConnectionPool Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, scrapy, beautifulsoup

estaba intentando seguir un tutorial sobre scraping de [gruposothis](https://www.gruposothis.com/web-scraping-convertir-la-web-fuente-datos/), y me surge el siguiente error luego de un par de consultas.

El error en cuestión

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 284, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C9E10469E8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.orghttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //calcpad.blog/the-calcpad-language (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C9E10469E8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\Desktop\Machine learning\python\scraping_programming_lenguaje.py", line 116, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\Desktop\Machine learning\python\scraping_programming_lenguaje.py", line 106, in main
    e = edges()
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\Desktop\Machine learning\python\scraping_programming_lenguaje.py", line 38, in edges
    aux = requests.get(URL, timeout=6)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sebastián\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.orghttps', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //calcpad.blog/the-calcpad-language (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001C9E10469E8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))
```

Aquí el código:

```
def edges():

    print("Entro a edges")
    time.sleep(0.8)    # pause 5.5 seconds

    res = []
    for lang, URL in langsWikipedia():
        html = requests.get(URL, timeout=6).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('table', class_='infobox')
        if table:
            tr = table.find_all('tr')
            for i in range(len(tr)):
                if tr[i].th and tr[i].th.text == 'Influenced':                    

                    for a in tr[i + 1].td.find_all('a', recursive=False):
                        res.append((lang, a.text))
                    break


    print("SALGO de edges()")
    time.sleep(0.8)    # pause 5.5 seconds
    return list(set(res))
```

A mi entender el error se produce en la linea de `html = requests.get(URL, timeout=6).text` debido a un exceso de consulta o alguna mala configuración de mis puertos. No recuerdo haber hecho cambios en estos y ya he intentado desactivando los antivirus y el firewall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba enque uno de URL tomados de la consulta era incorrecto, así que lo pude solucionar evadiendole con un if. Luego surgió otro problema que solucioné aumentando el tiempo de espera. Aumenté el timeout a 12.

Comment: Sebastian , si tu repuesta resolvió tu problema no olvides marcarla como respuesta aceptada!